# Cannot connect to postgres over external ip

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, port

I am trying to connect to postgres database that is on a server and i am trying to connect an application to database

The port 5432 on the open port check tool is closed, but on server in listening
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sGVx.png)

here is my postgres.conf and pg_hba.conf
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE6us.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD9Zu.png)

Comment: What are the connection messages you are seeing?

Comment: Remote server port is not accessible, but on server it is, that has intervening firewall all over it.